# how to calculate percentage variation between two values in same one column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe with the total population number by year.

```
import pandas as pd
cases_df = pd.DataFrame(data=cases_list, columns=['Year', 'Population', 'Nation'])
cases_df.head(7)


    Year       Population       Nation
0   2019    328239523   United States
1   2018    327167439   United States
2   2017    325719178   United States
3   2016    323127515   United States
4   2015    321418821   United States
5   2014    318857056   United States
6   2013    316128839   United States
```

I want to calculate how much the population has increased from the year 2013 to 2019 by calculating the percentage change between two values (2013 and 2019):

```
{[(328239523 - 316128839)/ 316128839] x 100 }
```

How can I do this? Thank you very much!!

ps. some advice to remove index?
0
1
2
3
4
5
6

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the pandas method called percentage change.
Syntax:

```
df.pct_change()
```

In your case the code will be as follows:

```
df1 = df.groupby(level='Population').pct_change()
print(df1)
```

Comment: it returns me that error       ValueError: level name Population is not the name of the index

Comment: it doesn't work, can you help me?

Comment: Hey, sorry been a bit time using stackoverflow. The solutions in this case is 'df['Population'].pct_change()'.